# Issue with sending ctrl+z via c code and sending data to server using HTTPDATA AT command using GSM module

Tags: c, embedded, gsm, esp32, firmware

OS: Ubuntu(20.04)
MCU: ESP WROOM 32
GSM/LTE: Cavli C10AM
Operation: AT+HTTPDATA

I am using ESP32 to interface with Cavli C10AM module. I am initialising it successfully and able to send the basic AT commands and receiving correct responses. I am able to initiate the HTTP communication and able to GET the response from the server using HTTPGET AT command.

Now, I am trying to post the data to the URL. After setting the URL, Content type using AT+HTTPPARA AT command, I am sending AT+HTTPDATA to post the data to server. In response to this I am correctly getting '>' symbol. At parsing this response, I am sending data (json) using a string (i.e., I am storing the json in a string and trying to post it). The process requires me to send the ctrl+z at the end. I am doing it after sending the data by sending '26' via UART. I have also tried '/032' for the same but I am not getting 'OK' response. I'm getting +CME ERROR 3 response.

The error message is:

```
I (46271) RX_TASK: Wrote 42 bytes
Command number is : 11
Written bytes are: AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
 
I (48771) RX_TASK: Read 6 bytes: '
OK
'
Read bytes are 
OK
: 
I (49771) RX_TASK: Wrote 13 bytes
Command number is : 12
Written bytes are: AT+HTTPDATA
 
I (52271) RX_TASK: Read 4 bytes: '
> '
Read bytes are 
> : 
Inside HTTPDATA function 
 '>' is in 2th byte and value is >: 
Sent bytes in HTTPDATA ctrl+z are 2 and buffer is 26  
received bytes are 0
```

The way I am parsing '>' symbol is :

```
                #define CTRL_Z 26     // for sending ctrl+z
                char buffer[10];


                //I enter the HTTPDATA function here
                if(i==12){
                printf("Inside HTTPDATA function \n");
                char data[] = "{\"name\": \"S-1234\", \"mac\": \"123456789abc\"}";

               // Parsing the response from AT+HTTPDATA, on occurance of '>', send data via UART
                for(int k=0; k<27; k++ ){
                    if(response[k] == '>'){
                        sprintf (buffer, "%d", CTRL_Z); //storing ctrl+z in 'buffer'
                        int sent_bytes=0;
                        printf(" '>' is in %dth byte and value is %c: \n", k, response[k]);
                        sent_bytes = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, data, strlen(data));
                        vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                        sent_bytes = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, buffer, strlen(buffer));
         printf("Sent bytes in HTTPDATA ctrl+z are %d and buffer is %s\n", sent_bytes, buffer);
                        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                        const int rcvd_cert =  uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_1, data_2, RX_BUF_SIZE, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
                        ESP_LOGI("CERT_WRITTEN_TASK", "Read %d bytes: '%s'", rcvd_cert, data_2);
                        printf("received bytes are %d \n", rcvd_cert);
```

But, after sending via UART, if I read using uart_read_bytes as mentioned above, instead of reading 'OK', I am not receiving any response. (response pasted above the code).

Is the way I am parsing '>' is wrong or is the way I'm sending ctrl+z is wrong I have no idea. If anyone has this solution please help me out with this thing. Thanks in advance for any leads.

Comment: It's usually best to test these AT commands manually first, using a serial terminal program and typing the commands in yourself. You get a much, much quicker feedback loop to help you find the mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong, as you're converting the Ctrl-Z into its decimal representation:

```
sprintf (buffer, "%d", CTRL_Z); //storing ctrl+z in 'buffer'
```

You're not storing Ctrl-Z, you're storing the string "26". This would be correct:

```
sprintf (buffer, "%c", CTRL_Z); //storing ctrl+z in 'buffer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Written bytes are: AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json\x1a"
the above line ended with CTRL+Z which in HEX is 0x1A

whit the escape character (\) followed by the value in HEX, you can send the CTRL+Z that the moden expects as the end of the message